# How do I display border lines for my search bar with React native

Tags: react-native

I need the border lines to be displayed but here only the sides can be seen it is blank in the top and bottom

I have tried this using react native elements
[Here is what I wanted to acheive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86FJp.png)
 [Here is what I got with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRkZk.png)

```
<SearchBar
  round
    lightTheme
    icon={{ type: 'font-awesome', name: 'search' }}
    placeholder="Buscar producto..."
    platform="ios"
    containerStyle={{
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    }}
    inputStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}  
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to find which prop that `SearchBar` gives you access to is the one you want. `inputStyle` only styles the `TextInput` component, while `containerStyle` styles the whole big `SearchBar` (which has some extra padding and stuff that we don't want).

The prop you want is [`inputContainerStyle`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html#inputcontainerstyle) which will style the container around `TextInput` and the bits on the left and right. So to give a border you could simply do:

```
<SearchBar
  round
  lightTheme
  icon={{ type: 'font-awesome', name: 'search' }}
  placeholder="Buscar producto..."
  platform="ios"
  inputContainerStyle={{ 
    backgroundColor: 'white', 
    borderColor: 'grey',
    borderWidth: 1
  }} 
/>
```